# 日本語に違和感: 新しいアクティビティのある n 件の質問

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

対象: 質問一覧を見ていて裏で更新があった場合

[image: 新しいアクティビティのある 2 件の質問]

Comment: 翻訳を登録しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 新しいアクティビティのある 2 件の質問

2 件の質問が更新されました