# 日本語に違和感: 1の質問が更新されました

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

質問一覧を開いていて、裏で更新があった時に表示されます。

[日本語に違和感: 新しいアクティビティのある n 件の質問](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/31/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AB%E9%81%95%E5%92%8C%E6%84%9F-%E6%96%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%93%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%81%AE%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B-n-%E4%BB%B6%E3%81%AE%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F) の適用ミスでしょうか:

[image: 1の質問が更新されました]

「1 件の質問が更新されました」の方が自然です。